# Are Characters in 5e allowed to buy Items with their Background Gold?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, equipment, wealth

Assuming I have a new character that chooses starting equipment instead of rolling for gold and buying items. Can I exchange some of the gold I got from the background for additional gear from the "Adventuring Gear" Table?